# How to read a file to a array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, file

I have a file and a given matrix size K by N. I want to read that file and save into that array. In which K is determined from size of file divides for N. If that division is not integer, I will add zeros padding at the end of last packet. As the figure, the zeros padding is denoted by yellow color. Finally, I can store the information of file into a array K by N. Could you help me implement that problem by matlab code. Thank you in advance 
[image]
Update: I would like to share my code. Please look at my code and let me know if it have any problem

```
file='Lenna.bmp';
N=3;
fid=fopen(file,'r');
inter_list=fread(fid,'*uint8'); % 
fclose(fid);

%% Add padding
[m n]=size(inter_list);
numpadding=N-rem(m*n,N);
inter_list(end+numpadding,:)=0;
packet = reshape( inter_list.', [],N); 
[K N]=size(packet);
```

I found a problem that is my inter_list is constructed as following

```
66
77
54
0
12
0
0
0
0
0
54
0
0
0
40
```

If I set N=3 that mean the first packet is [66 77 54], second packet is [0 12 0] and so on. However, when I use that code

```
packet = reshape( inter_list.', [],N);  % N=3
```

Then output is,

```
66  -58 109
77  102 -60
54  82  99
```

How to achieve my expected result that is

```
 66    77   54
 0     12   0
```

You can download the file at [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ykzhqkjva3ipdp/Lenna.bmp?dl=0)

Comment: You should read [the doc](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/low-level-file-i-o.html) about file I/O and try to start at least by yourself. With only a few lines of code you'll be able to get most of what you want (only the padding may not be trivial). When you are at that stage, post the code you've tried and we'll be able to help you better. Also, you question is not well defined as it is, you need to know what type of data you are reading (text/binary, and if binary, which type and what length).

Comment: Thank Hoki. I update my code. Let see my update

Comment: Well done. I just ran your code and it works absolutely fine. Minor detail, you do not need to transpose `inter_list.'` in your reshape operation (the reshape is going to put things right anyway). Another detail, if you are reading `bmp` file I would use `uint8` (unsigned) instead of `int8`, you do not need sign information for this type of data, it will only makes things confusing. Apart from that it runs ok and return the right result. Do you have a problem with the current output ?

Comment: I see, Could you see my new problem. I found a problem when I reshape matrix. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab is a "***column major***" language (unlike many other). It means the elements of an array will be read/accessed/stored column wise in memory.

Quick example: The array:

```
A = [ 1 2 3
      4 5 6 ] ;
```

Will be written in memory sequentially (*there is no other way*) by reading from top to bottom, then left to right (as opposed as "from left to right, then top to bottom"). So in memory, it look like:

```
A = [ 1 4 2 5 3 6 ] ;
```

This is also how these values would be indexed if you choose the sequential indexing instead of the 2D matrix indexing.
ex: `A(1,3)=3` is the same as `A(5)=3`.

---

The [`reshape`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html#bud6j0x-1_1) function, like most Matlab function, will use this ordering as default.

*<sub>(Matlab doc used to be much more explicit about this but in the recent documentation I could only find a small reference to that at the bottom of one of the example: "The elements in B also maintain their **columnwise order** from A.")</sub>*

---

So in your case, you want your packets to contain **`N` *sequential*** values, you have to specify that to the `reshape` function as the **first** parameter:

```
packet = reshape( inter_list , N , [] ) ;
```

Now that will give you a `[N K]` matrix instead of a `[K N]`, this is where the transpose operation will achieve what you want. It has to be applied on the result of the reshape, *not in the input*. So your full instruction should be:

```
packet = reshape( inter_list , N , [] ).' ; %'// the transpose ".'" operation is applied on the result of the reshape operation
```

The rest of your code is ok.